# Google Maps API 3 - Check if marker is in view

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I see that there is a getVisible call, but that only checks if the marker is on the map NOT if the marker is in the current view.

I want to check if the marker is in the current view bounds?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I guess you want

```
map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell map that your markers should be contained within view by adding following code

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition()) 
});
```

Here bound_changed event is triggered.